# How germa66 travelled from north blue to south blue

Tags: one-piece

I was watching whole cake island arc in anime and it showed Germa 66 snail like ship climbing over red line.

But as far as I know, only way to cross grand line is through reverse mountain which has sea water flowing

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

The grand line is indeed what splits the world in half along the horizontal axis but ultimately it's only a body of water, surrounded by more water. You theoretically could sail North/South across the grand line without incident but that would entail sailing across the calm belts where no winds blow and gigantic neptunians tear ships apart. The thing is, the calm belts have already been conquered, the marines learned to embed seastones in the hulls of their ships to ward off neptunians and propel ships without the use of wind which allows them to cross the calm belts at will. [image: Seastones] Its hard to imagine the obscenely rich and technologically advanced Germa66 who can cross the red line in mecha boats don't also have access to seastone to cross the calm belts.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out this map. you will see that one can go over the Redline/ Grand Line/ through Reverse Mountain from one sea to another.

[image]

Comment: You cannot use reverse mountain to traverse between the 4 seas, if you recall the events from volume 12 when the straw hats enter the grand line those channels that seem to crisscross reverse mountain are actually wicked fast currents that run up the mountain and converge at the top before launching ships into the grand line. You would need a ship capable of going against dangerously powerful currents to enter one of the four seas.

Comment: Well of course but we were talking about Germa66, not some village townfolks who want to get to South Blue. That is why I put that option there. Anyway, Germa most likely climbed the Red Line to get to all 4 seas. I bet there are some kind of transporters for ordinary people that dont want to get in the GL and only to one of the Blues.

Comment: I understand we're talking about Germa66 but that map is misleading in that it appears that there's some sort of 4 way canal between the blues at reverse mountain which is not the case. I don't doubt the Germa66 couldn't spend a few weeks climbing along the red line to get over the grand line and calm belts but it has never been established how the did it. Lastly, there's no indication of people crossing between the blues at all, Sanji was born in North Blue and ended up in the East but he's a Vinsmoke, otherwise I don't think any non-marine/world class pirates have been between blues